# Password-Protect all pages in a non-Wordpress site/directory with Wordpress login ('Client Showroom')

Tags: php, wordpress, password-protection

I've got a fun little dilemma here:

I'm trying to create a 'client showroom' where clients can log in to view their (non-wordpress) test sites before the sites go live. Account managers from my team need to be able to log in through the Wordpress CMS and add links to a WP post or page listing links to all the sites available to a specific client.

The client needs to be able to log in via Wordpress to access this page (with the list of links to non-wordpress sites/subdomains), and each page in these subdomains needs to be password-protected with the same Wordpress login.

For example, Client1 goes to clients.mycompany.com/client1. Logs in, sees a list of their sites:

```
clients.mycompany.com/client1amazingproject1
clients.mycompany.com/client1amazingproject2
clients.mycompany.com/client1amazingproject3
```

These are links to non-WP pages that need to be manually password-protected using the WP login system.  It's relatively straightforward to include a PHP snippet in each page to add the WP login, but what if the test site is 100+ pages? Ideally, I'd like to be able to upload the /client1amazingproject1 subdirectory and do something **simple** that would password-protect all pages in the directory. My server doesn't allow prepending/appending via htaccess or php.ini, so that option's out.

TL;DR:

- **Is there a way to use the WP login to easily password-protect every page in the subdirectory /client1amazingproject1, without having to manually include a php snippet in each page?**
- **Are there any plugins, etc. that would make this task easier?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible without adding code to those files. Do you have a common header file?

Comment: @Igupta, there's no common header file.